# Phonegap apple maps: navigate from current location

Tags: cordova, apple-maps

I am developing an App for iOS with Phonegap. I added a link to open Apple's Maps-App. I want to navigate the User from his current location to a specific address, but I can't get Maps to use "current location" as startpoint.
I use the following link, it opens up Maps fine, but I don't know the value for the "saddr"-key:

```
<a href="maps:daddr=MyStreet 1, My City&saddr=">Navigate me</a>
```

I could use Phonegap's Geolocation-API to find out the user's current position, but I don't want to make iOS ask the user, if he wants to let my app access the GPS-sensor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are handling the url, but the destination should also be url encoded (e.g. escape spaces with %20).

Final url:

```
<a href="maps:daddr=MyStreet%201,%20My%20City&saddr=Current%20Location">Navigate me</a>
```